# Plotting incoming TCP data in real-time (filtering out strings?)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot, tkinter, tcp

I'm trying to plot pairs of data values coming in from an instrument over TCP.
I can successfully receive these values and print them to my UI, but I can't seem to figure out how to plot these values dynamically as they are being received. I've played around with a couple graphing libraries and animate, but the main problem seems to be filtering out the string labels and unwanted characters so I can only plot the float values being received.

Here is my code:

```
    s = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
    #s.settimeout(10)
    s.connect((TCP_IP, TCP_PORT))
    s.sendall(MESSAGE)
    #s.shutdown(socket.SHUT_WR)

    s.setblocking(0) # set port to nonblocking

    begin=time.time()     


    while(1):
      if loop == 15:
        text1.insert(END, "Stopped Recieving Continious Data... Press SEND to continue recieving data \n")
        text1.insert(END, " To Stop Continious Transimisson, SEND *** 0")
        text1.see("end")
        break;
    if logData and time.time()-begin > timeout:
        #print("in if 1")
        break
    elif time.time()-begin > timeout*2:
        #print("in if 2")
        break
    try:    
        logData = s.recv(BUFFER_SIZE).strip('\t\r\n')
        f.write(logData)
        f.write('\n')
        if logData:
            udpData(logData) #prints to UI
            print(repr(logData))
            begin=time.time()
            loop = loop + 1
        else:
            time.sleep(0.1)
    except:
        pass

    # perform filtering of strings here or within while loop try?
    # x = logData

    #plt.plot(x, color = 'red', marker = 'o', linestyle = 'dashed', linewidth = 2)
    #plt.show()
```

This function is activated by a send message button press within my UI and receives the data successfully and prints and writes to a file. How would I interpret the data and plot when I send a command that gives me a pair of values like this:

```
    CCT 1
    Conc1: 1004.5    Conc2: 3003.2
    Conc1: 567.4     Conc2: 4034.2
    ...              ...
```

Also it seems like there is a \t char after Conc1:, the values, and Conc2:

Thanks for any input or help :)

Plotting function using text file data has been written too, but strings are in that file as above and my animate function will not parse them correctly, but the main problems is doing this as I relieve data and not from the text file I write to. :

```
    def animate(i):
       xs = []
       ys = []
      with open("C:\\Users\\aeros\\Desktop\\output6.txt") as graph_data:
          for line in graph_data:
                x, y = line.split(" ")
                xs.append(x)
                ys.append(y)

 ax1.clear()
 ax1.plot(xs, ys)
```

Comment: matplotlib includes an animate function that has many examples online; try some of those.

Comment: I have tried most of those, the issue lies in parsing my data so that the animate functions or graphing libraries can take in the values properly and not give me errors because it is receiving strings in the data.

Comment: Then show us what you have tried. We need a [mcve] before we can help you.

Comment: Added what I tried, but it doesn't really address my issue of receiving the data and plotting it dynamically.

Answer (score 0):

Since you won't show us a complete example, all I can do is show you an example I have lying around and hope you can adapt it.

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import matplotlib.animation as animation
import requests

URL = 'https://poloniex.com/public?command=returnTicker'

def poloapi():
    """get a single datapoint
    replace this with your code that returns a single datapoint"""
    data = requests.get(URL).json()
    return float(data['ETH_BCH']['highestBid'])

def animate(i):
    ydata.append(poloapi())
    line.set_data(range(len(ydata)), ydata)
    plt.ylim(min(ydata), max(ydata))
    plt.xlim(0, len(ydata))
    return line,

ydata = [poloapi()]
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(1,1,1)
line, = ax1.plot(ydata, marker='o', markersize=10, markerfacecolor='green')
ani = animation.FuncAnimation(fig, animate, interval=30000)
plt.show()
```

Comment: Thank you for this! The above examples I provided is my complete example of my attempt. I think this is a good skeleton to do what I'm trying to accomplish, but I'm also looking for pointers of how to filter the strings out of my TCP data stream. Because plt won't process those strings right? and I don't want them there obviously.

Comment: That's a different question. Make a new post (mabe better in a beginner forum like learnpython.reddit.com). Be sure to include an example of your TCP data and an example of what you want to extract.

Comment: Will do! Thanks